# RTMP video with emscripten C/C++ to Javascript LLVM compiler

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I understand emscripten is a super powerful way to encode C code into Javascript.

Is it possible to use this for video, capture the webcam and stream this over RTMP using something like the rtmpdump library?

Answer (score 2):

rtmpdump can be recompiled to javascript using Emscripten. However, that does not guarantee that the recompiled code is capable of executing within a Javascript environment in the way that the RTMP spec requires (namely the requirement for TCP).

**Steps used to recompile rtmpdump with Emscripten:**

1. Obtain [latest portable emscripten tools](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html):
2. Obtain rtmpdump source:

   *git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/rtmpdump*
3. Clear make cache

*make clean*

4. Set C compiler to CC in Makefile

Edit the rtmpdump Makefile on line 5 to the following:

*CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)cc*

5. Run emmake to create bytecode from make output:

*emmake make CRYPTO=*

(Per rtmpdump README, I opted to use 'CRYPTO=' to build without SSL support as it was giving errors)

6. Run emcc to compile and link resulting bytecode into javascript:

*emcc -01 ./librtmp/*.o rtmpdump.o -o rtmpdump.js*

7. Run the recompiled rtpmpdump.js:

*chmod 755 rtmpdump.js*

*node rtmpdump.js -r rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/STREAM_NAME*

Of course, we will need a live RTMP stream to test against.

**Steps to create live RTMP stream:**

1. Obtain latest [node-rtsp-rtmp-server](https://github.com/iizukanao/node-rtsp-rtmp-server):

*git clone
https://github.com/iizukanao/node-rtsp-rtmp-server.git*
2. Add an mp4 to livestream over RTMP:

(Using Big Buck Bunny as our test video)

*cd node-rtps-rtmp-server/*

*npm install -d*

*cd file/*

*wget http://download.bl4ender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4*
4. Start the RTMP server

*sudo coffee server.coffee*

3. Publish mp4 to RTMP server with ffmpeg

*ffmpeg -re -i /node-rtsp-rtmp-server/file/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/STREAM_NAME*

**Observations**

You should be able to confirm that the RTMP stream is successfully published by connecting with something like VLC Media Player.  Once we confirm the stream is properly running, we can test rtmpdump.js with:

*node rtmpdump.js -4 rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/STREAM_NAME -o out.flv*

However, we immediately encounter:

*ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket.  113 (Host is unreachable)*

**Conclusion**

While my answer explores a path to recompiling rtmpdump and it's supporting libraries (librtmp) to Javascript, it does not produce a working implementation.

Some [quick research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-Time_Messaging_Protocol) concludes that RTMP relies on TCP communication for transmission from server to client.  [Javascript by nature, confines communication to XHR and WebSocket requests only](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100827/why-no-support-for-tcp-sockets-in-javascript).  The steps I have outlined for recompilation of rtmpdump produces XHR requests for the RTMP_Connect0 method which are HTTP based (i.e. != TCP).  It may be possible to rewrite an RTMP client to use websockets and pass those connections over to TCP using something like [WebSockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify), however, if successful you would move the RTMP's dependency on flash to a dependency on Websockify if you intend to consume an RTMP stream.  Producing a flashless RTMP client does not appear to be a simple matter of recompiling RTMP to Javascript as the transport mechanism (TCP) must be accounted for.

**Notes**

For anyone looking to pick up on this work, be aware that testing against a remote stream from a browser running a theoretically proper rtmp implementation in Javascript would require that CORS is enabled on the remote host due to Same-Origin-Policy. See: https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/blob/master/docs/cors.md